# Finding Fibonacci of a number using recursion method

Tags: recursion, fibonacci-numbers

Is it a bad idea to use recursion method to find the fibonacci of a number? If yes/no support answer with reasons

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this question?

Comment: There is a direct formula, but for relatively large $n$, we need a high precision. Since there are properties of the fibonacci numbers, you can apply an efficient recursive calculation of $F_n$

Comment: Matrix formulation with fast exponentiation is pretty fast.

Comment: @Sil Matrix exponentiation with repeated squaring isn't as fast a solution as it seems, because we can't neglect the fact that, since $F_n$ has $O(n)$ digits, the multiplication is surprisingly slow. Contrary to a common misconception that stems from neglecting this, matrix exponentiation can't evaluate $F(n)$ in $o(n)$ time. Nothing can: the space complexity is already linear.

Comment: @J.G. Well, in practice it is comparably faster then standard approach by accumulating sums (simple comparison in python of both approaches demonstrates that).

Comment: By the way this link has nice summary of the different ways https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms. An of course this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661633/finding-out-nth-fibonacci-number-for-very-large-n (they also touch on the same thing as the above comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon my Python (not to mention my neglecting of the case $n<0$).

If this question means what I think it does, the point is that e.g. `def fibonacci(n): return n if n<2 else fibonacci(n-2)+fibonacci(n-1)` runs in exponential time, whereas

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n<2: return n
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(n-2): a, b = b, a+b
    return b
```

is much more efficient. There are other subexponential approaches, too, such as one using $F_{2n-1}=F_{n-1}^2+F_n^2,\,F_{2n}=F_n(F_n+2F_{n-1})$.